# is it possible to use the discovery module from the Google apiclient in Cloud Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-genomics

I have a simple python script that does something like this:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
ggSvc = discovery.build ( 'genomics', 'v1', credentials=credentials )

body = { "readGroupSetIds": [readGroupSetId],
         "referenceName": args.chr,
         "start": args.pos-2,
         "end": args.pos+2,
         "pageSize": 256 }

r = ggSvc.reads().search ( body=body ).execute()
```

is it possible to do this from Datalab or is my best option to use the requests module and then construct and post the http request that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will install the google api python client 
`!pip install google-api-python-client`

You can also run commands using the `%%bash` cell magic option.

For example,

```
%%bash
pip install google-api-python-client
```

Comment: thanks, I don't know why I wasn't thinking along those lines  --  also I just found [this](https://github.com/googlegenomics/datalab-examples/blob/master/datalab/genomics/Getting%20started%20with%20the%20Genomics%20API.ipynb) googlegenomics example on github